# Is there a way to get the previously received message by id in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  Message     week

10 A            1
11 A            1
12 C            1
10 B            2
12 B            2
```

How can I get one like this?:

```
ID  Message     week  previous

10 A            1     nan
11 A            1     nan
12 C            1     nan
10 B            2     A
12 B            2     A
```

Comment: 12's previous message was C

Comment: This is a task, not a question. What have you tried, what problems did you experience with your code?

Comment: I have tried things like C2['i1']=C2['Trigger_no'][(C2.Semana.shift(1))] which I know doesn't work, but to at least experiment with shift

Answer (score 2):

Use an `asof` merge to bring the closest message in the past. `allow_exact_matches=False` prevents merging on the same week.

```
df = df.sort_values('week')  # Only b/c merge_asof requires sorted input

res = (pd.merge_asof(df, df.rename(columns={'Message': 'previous'}), 
                     on='week', by='ID',
                     direction='backward', allow_exact_matches=False))
```

---

```
   ID Message  week previous
0  10       A     1      NaN
1  11       A     1      NaN
2  12       C     1      NaN
3  10       B     2        A
4  12       B     2        C
```

Comment: `merge_asof` is such a beautiful method in pandas!

Comment: I tried this and it worked great! Thank you very much! I have a question that's sort of irrelevant, but I wanted to ask you if you think that achieving this with a function that looks at rows is also possible. Not that I need it, I just want to understand how to define functions that look at rows with IDs that repeat. Thank you

Comment: @moltke_colombia That method would be more similar to what @Erfan proposed. `groupby` is a way to create subsets of your DataFrame that all have the same value for the grouping key, so `df.groupby("ID")` would group the DataFrame into groups containing all rows for every unique 'ID'. You can then apply functions to those groups of rows, or use the built-in aggregations, like shift, (that are very efficient).

Comment: Thank you! I see what you're saying. Thank you so very much for your help, I voted positive for your answer but since I'm new it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `groupby` with `Series.shift` here:

```
df["previous"] = df.groupby("ID")["Message"].shift()
```

```
   ID Message  week previous
0  10       A     1      NaN
1  11       A     1      NaN
2  12       C     1      NaN
3  10       B     2        A
4  12       B     2        C
```

Comment: Nice one! Beat me to it, definitely an easier method if `['ID', 'week']` aren't duplicated

Comment: Thanks. Yes the ID field is crucial here to be "clean", I agree.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is sort of the method I tried originally but failed. Thank you very much.